# GEE export too large data

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm want to export some pixels with feature to my google drive:

```
var exportData = function(table, prefix, year) {
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: table,
    description: prefix,
    folder: year,  
    fileNamePrefix: prefix
  });
};

var first = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(-70.48, 43.3631))
                .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
                .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
                .first();

var samples = first.sample({
  numPixels: 1000,
  geometries: true,

});

exportData(samples, 'county', '2019');
```

But if, just if, the samples is very big, the download will get an error like this:

```
ID: ZHJAJBZ3NI6Y2CMGVMDDTJPP
Phase: Failed
Runtime: 1m (started 2023-05-08 08:51:57 -0500)
Attempted 1 time
Error: Image.reduceRegions: Computed value is too large. (Error code: 3)
```

So my question is that, is there any method to automatically split the too big value to download? for example, like this:

```
if(samples is big):
  sample_1, sample_2 = samples.split()
  exportData(sample_1, 'county_1', '2019')
  exportData(sample_2, 'county_2', '2019')
```

if not, could you tell me what's the most elegant method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var clipped = first.mosaic().clip(area)
```

For the area you can use a polygon inside the code-editor.

For a example, how to use it watch [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b455ba8cf4b5bee822bb7ff8935e6209).